Non-holonomic modules for $\mathcal{D}(X)$, where $X$ is an affine open subspace of the affine space
Let $k$ be any algebraically closed field of zero characteristic.
Let $A_n$ be the n rank Weyl algebra, and $M$ a finitely generated module. We have that $GK(M)$ is always a positive integer and
(Berstein inequality) $GK(M)\geq n$. If $GK(M)=n$, $M$ is called an holonomic module.
For some time, mainly by lack of counterexamples, people believed that all irreducible modules for the Weyl algebra were holonomic.
This changed when Stafford in 1985 produced, for $A_n$, finitely generated irreducible modules of GK dimension $2n-1$. Soon, Bernstein and Lunts would show that a generic irreducible module was non-holonomic. However, despite Bernstein and Lunts result, it remains difficult to produce such modules.
Now let Y be any smooth affine variety and $D(Y)$ the ring of differential operators on Y. Any finitely generarated $D(Y)$-module $M$ will have positive integer GK dimension, and
(Generalization of Bernstein inequality) $GK(M) \geq dim , Y$. If $GK(M)=dim \, Y$, $M$ will be called holonomic.
Question 1: What is known about non-holonomic irreducible modules in this generality?
Now I assume $Y=X$ is an affine open subset of $k^n$. $X$ might even be a principal open subset.
Question 2: what we know about irreducible non-holonomic module in this second much more specific situation?

Recall that for $f: X \to Y$ a morphism of smooth affine algebraic varieties, we have a pullback functor $f^\ast$ from $D_Y$-modules to $D_X$-modules. $f^\ast$ is computed by taking the $\mathcal O$-module pullback, i.e. $\mathcal O_X \otimes_{\mathcal O_Y} -$. (I consider abelian categories, nothing is derived.)
Lemma: suppose $f$ is an open immersion. If $M$ is an irreducible $D_Y$-module, then $f^*M$ is zero or an irreducible $D_X$-module.
Proof: The hypothesis on $f$ implies $D_X = f^* D_Y$. Now suppose $N \subseteq f^*M$ is a $D_X$-submodule. Since $f$ is an open immersion, $N$ is generated as a $\mathcal O_X$-module by $N \cap M$. Now $N \cap M$ is closed under $D_Y$ so $N \cap M$ is zero or $M$, and the Lemma follows.
Now if $f: X \to Y$ is étale, then the pullback of an irreducible module may no longer be irreducible, e.g. if $X = Y \sqcup Y$. I hesitantly suspect that the pullback of an irreducible module will be finite length. If so, I would then investigate the GK dimension of the composition factors.
Finally, every smooth algebraic variety over $k$ is locally étale over an open affine subset of $\mathbb{A}^n$, c.f. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01V7. So considering affine opens and étale morphisms is enough, at least affine locally.
